# Moving GPO Deployed Software install files: user endpoints not updating

Tags: group-policy

A bunch of our software is deployed via GPO (both Assigned and Published), but the paths to said installers are on an old server `\\foo`.

I've set up DFS and want to move these installers to a new location `\\domain\dfs\software`. So I've followed the instructions outlined [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2395088/how-to-change-the-msi-file-location-in-the-software-deployment-gpo-mut) to update the GPO's `msiFileList` value. Easy peasy.

[image: updated msiFileList value]

I double check the GPO settings: looks good.

[image: verified new gpo deployment source]

However, I log onto my test machine and try to install the software using "Install a Program from the Network", and see that it's still pointing to the old path:

[image: still pointing to the old path]

OK, maybe the GPO hasn't been applied.

- `gpresult /r`: Yup, GPO is applied
- `gpupdate /force`: No errors.
- Reboot: done

Well now that I'm sure this GPO is applied, let's try again. **Same thing.** I can manually point to the new location, but that's not a reasonable solution when trying to deploy to more than a few computers.

So what am I missing? Is there a GPO cache I need to clear somewhere?

### Version information

- Server: Windows 2008R2
- Test PC: Windows 10 Pro 1809

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I was unable to find any resolution to this. The only thing that worked was to remake each GPO.